# How to fix OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid with Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to log into my Fidelity account, using Selenium, and Fidelity.  I've made sure that I'm using the correct webdriver (version 78 for my Chrome version 78).  I think this has to do with the only Chrome webdriver is 32-bit and I'm using 64-bit.  This is the last error I'm getting.  It opens the webpage, put my user name and password, and then I think on the button click it crashes or right before it.

```py
from selenium import webdriver


def test_bot(username, password):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
    br = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    br.get("https://www.fidelity.com")
    br.implicitly_wait(10)

    user = br.find_element_by_id('userId-input')
    user.clear()
    user.send_keys(username)

    pwd = br.find_element_by_id('password')
    pwd.clear()
    pwd.send_keys(password)

    btn = br.find_element_by_id('fs-login-button')
    btn.click()


test_bot("MYUSERNAME", "MYPASSWORD")
```

Here's the error I'm getting.

```
Exception ignored in: <function Popen.__del__ at 0x03957270>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Notebook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 860, in __del__
    self._internal_poll(_deadstate=_maxsize)
  File "C:\Users\Notebook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1216, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

I'm using Pycharm and Selenium.

Comment: have you tried by commenting the `chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])` line?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I tried commenting it out, and it still didn't work.  That line prevents Chrome from yelling at you for using automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send *character sequence* to the **Usename** and **Password** field you you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  #options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  #options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.fidelity.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#userId-input"))).send_keys("Brandon")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#password").send_keys("Jacobson")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button#fs-login-button").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  #options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  #options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.fidelity.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='userId-input']"))).send_keys("Brandon")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password']").send_keys("Jacobson")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='fs-login-button']").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Your CSS_selector worked!  Thank you.  I had to change options= to :
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)